# Conversion from HEX to SIGNED DEC in python

Tags: python

I have a file with HEX data I want to convert it into SIGNED DECIMAL using python.
`int('0xffd2',16)` is not the solution since it converts the HEX to unsigned DEC. Any idea how to do it?

```
0xffd2, 65490

0xffcb, 65483

0xffcb, 65483

0xffcc, 65484

0x10, 16

0xc, 12

0xd, 13

0x0, 0

0xfffe, 65534
```

Comment: Give of an example of a hex string that would encode to a negative number.

Comment: 0xffe5 ===> -27 / val2=`perl -e " print unpack('s', pack 's', hex('0xffe5'))"`/ echo $val2

Answer (score 15):

You can interpret the bytes as a two's complement signed integer using bitwise operations. For example, for a 16-bit number:

```
def s16(value):
    return -(value & 0x8000) | (value & 0x7fff)
```

Therefore:

```
>>> s16(int('0xffd2', 16))
-46
>>> s16(int('0xffcb', 16))
-53
>>> s16(int('0xffcc', 16))
-52
>>> s16(int('0x10', 16))
16
>>> s16(int('0xd', 16))
13
>>> s16(int('0x0', 16))
0
>>> s16(int('0xfffe', 16))
-2
```

This can be extended to any bit-length string, by setting the masks so the  first mask matches the most-significant bit (`0x8000 == 1 << 15 == 0b1000000000000000`) and the second mask matches the all the remaining bits (`0x7fff == (1 << 15) - 1 == 0b0111111111111111`).

Answer (score 6):

Once you have the unsigned value, it's very easy to convert to signed.

```
if value >= 0x8000:
    value -= 0x10000
```

This is for a 16-bit number. For a 32-bit number just add 4 zeros to each of the magic constants. Those constants can also be calculated as `1 << (bits - 1)` and `1 << bits`.