# Converting hex to negative int in Python

Tags: python, pandas, hex

I want to convert hex in column x into correct negative int as seen in column "true", but instead i got result in column y.

```
x        y     true
fdf1   65009   -527
```

I tried this (I know it's not correct)

```
df["y"] = df["x"].apply(int,base=16)
```

and from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563786/conversion-from-hex-to-signed-dec-in-python/32276534) I know this function:

```
def s16(value):
    return -(value & 0x8000) | (value & 0x7fff)

a = s16(int('fdf1', 16))
print(a)
```

can convert single value into correct one but how do you apply it to make a new column in Pandas data frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lambda` function:

```
df["y"] = df["x"].apply(lambda x: s16(int(x, base=16)))
```

Or change function for cleaner code:

```
def s16(value):
    value = int(value, base=16)
    return -(value & 0x8000) | (value & 0x7fff)

df["y"] = df["x"].apply(s16)
print (df)
      x    y  true
0  fdf1 -527  -527
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to convert it to an integer and reinterpret it as a 16-bit integer by using `.astype`:

```
import numpy as np
df["y"] = df["x"].apply(lambda x: int(x, base=16)).astype(np.int16)
```

The dtype of column `y` will be `int16`, so any operation done on this column with other `int16`'s will keep the values between -32768 and 32767.